# influxdb Duplicate row for each item in a comma separated string

Tags: influxdb, flux

Say I have the following data where `strategies` is a string containing a comma separated list. I want to transform it in the query so that it looks like the second table (duplicate entries for each strategy)

```
name      | strategies
-----------------------
test1     | strat1,strat2,strat3
test2     | strat3,strat4



name      | strategy
---------------------
test1     | strat1
test1     | strat2
test1     | strat3
test2     | strat3
test2     | strat4
```

I've been trying to use strings.split but it errors on the last line:

```
import "strings"
import "array"

union(tables:
    from(bucket: "views")
        |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "views")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "views")
        |> map(fn: (r) => strings.split(v: r["strategies"], t: ",") |> array.map(fn: (x) => ({r with strategy: x})))
        |> map(fn: (r) => array.from(rows: r))
)
```

```
expected [stream[{
    A with
    strategy: string,
    strategies: string,
    _value: B,
    _time: time,
    _stop: time,
    _start: time,
    _measurement: string,
    _field: string,
}]] (array) but found stream[stream[{
    A with
    strategy: string,
    strategies: string,
    _value: B,
    _time: time,
    _stop: time,
    _start: time,
    _measurement: string,
    _field: string,
}]] (argument tables)flux
```

In case it helps, my ultimate goal is to filter by "strategies contains A or B or C or ... (unlimited, it is a multi-select variable in grafana)"

So I was thinking to do the duplication and then filter using `contains(v: r["strategy"], s: ${selected_strategies})`